# Where condition inside json_agg in postgres

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to return a JSON object from postgres that looks something like this:

```
[
{id: 1, name: "some organisation name", alias: [{alias:"alt name"}, {alias:"another name"}]}
...]
```

My query below works fine, except that I want to add a where condition, referencing the org_aliases table

```
SELECT json_build_object('id', table1.id, 'name', table1.name, 'alias', a.alias) as json
   FROM orgs table1
    CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
      SELECT json_agg(agg) AS alias
      FROM  (
        SELECT table2.alias as name
        FROM org_aliases table2
        WHERE 
            table2.org_id = table1.id
         ) agg
    ) a
    WHERE
        table1.name ilike 'nspcc' 
        or table2.alias ilike 'nspcc';
```

It fails on the last line (missing from condition on table2). I can see why it doesn't allow me to do this, as I'm referencing something inside a sub query.

My question, is what's the best way to handle this?
My only idea is that I need to join the org_aliases again so I can add a where condition. But if anyone has a better idea for how I structure the query to avoid duplication, that would be amazing.

Comment: Can you share sample input and expected output tables?

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/20b0b/6

Expected output:
{"id" : 1, "name" : "david", "alias" : [{"name":"dave"}]}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if it's exactly what you're looking for, but it does give you the required result for your example:

```
SELECT
  json_build_object('id', orgs.id
                   , 'name', name
                   , 'alias', json_agg(
                     json_build_object('name', alias)
                     )
                   )
FROM orgs
  LEFT JOIN org_aliases ON orgs.id = org_aliases.org_id
WHERE name ILIKE '%dave%'
OR alias ILIKE '%dave%'
GROUP BY
  orgs.id, orgs.name;
```

Edit: I would use a CTE to first find my target id and then get alle the data that I need. This makes it easy to understand (and debug):

```
WITH target AS (
   SELECT orgs.id
   FROM orgs
    LEFT JOIN org_aliases ON orgs.id = org_aliases.id
   WHERE name ILIKE '%dave%'
   OR alias ILIKE '%dave%'
)
SELECT
  json_build_object('id', orgs.id
                   , 'name', name
                   , 'alias', json_agg(
                     json_build_object('name', alias)
                     )
                   )
FROM target
  JOIN orgs ON target.id = orgs.id
  LEFT JOIN org_aliases ON orgs.id = org_aliases.org_id
GROUP BY
  orgs.id, orgs.name;
```

Comment: It's close, and you're right, it meets the test scenario. But what I wanted is to aggregate all the items in the org_aliases table in the output, rather than just the one that matched the where condition.

Comment: Show more samples from your tables, so that it's easier to debug with respect to what you need.

Comment: Updated test case
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/998cc/1
Expected:
{"id" : 1, "name" : "david", "alias" : [{"name":"dave"}, {"name":"big d"}]}

Comment: @Rusty: The new one works for your examples, does it also work for the rest of your data?

Comment: @Rusty: When you have to use LIKE, you might want to create a special index to speed things up. Check out the extension pg_trgm: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgtrgm.html#id-1.11.7.42.8

Comment: Ah that's brilliant - CTE is the way. That's helped a lot. And thanks, I'll look into the pg_trgm extension